# CodedUI : PropertyNames.ControlName doesn't work

Tags: winforms, coded-ui-tests

I'm searching for a customcontrol in a generic way, so I can re-use the function to find other customcontrols that match this one.

[Screenshot of the properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNZm0.jpg)

It has a Name and a ControlName. The name property will not always be filled in correctly, the ControlName will be!

When I look for the customcontrol like in the code below, he will locate and perform the requested actions.

> WinGroup group = new WinGroup(this.window);
> group.SearchProperties.Add(WinGroup.PropertyNames.Name,
> strGroupName, PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains);
> group.SearchConfigurations.Add(SearchConfiguration.NextSibling);

When I change the PropertyNames to ControlName, he will **not** locate the control! Which completely surprises me, because it is also unique.

What can be the cause of this? Am I missing something or am I doing something wrong?

Just to be safe, can PropertyNames.ControlName be used to find objects?

Comment: Why dont you try using the Control Id ?? I am guessing it should be unique as well!

Comment: Control Id in this specific case is 0. It's not unique.

Comment: That's Weird !! An ID should be unique inside a Scope !!! The control returned when u use Name & Controlname could be different. But, u had the right control earlier due to usage of next Sibling search configuration. The control returned when u use ControlName may not have Sibling.. Just a speculation !

Answer (score 0):

The question has been posted quite a bit of time ago, but I guess the answer may still be relevant to someone.

I'd suggest trying the following code:

`group.SearchProperties.Add("ControlName", "NameOfYourControlNameProperty");`

Answer (score -1):

ControlId is not a searchable property anyway. CodedUI is imperfect.